# lex prefix undefined symbol yyparse

Tags: c, lex

I am including two diferent lex parsers in my C code so to include the second one  defined a Prefix on it:

```
%option prefix="prep"
```

When I integrated this one in the global proyect It compiles without errors but on execution, If I try to call prepparse (formerly yyparse) I get this error:

```
undefined symbol: prepparse
```

I have tried including an external reference (not quite sure if this is correct):

```
extern int prepparse(void);
```

And defining it in the Lex header:

```
#define yyparse prepparse
```

But I still get the same error.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And you compiled `prep.lex.c` instead of `yy.lex.c` (At least that's the flex way of things when using `flex -Pprep`)?

Comment: I am compiling both lex.prep.c  and lex.yy.c, as they are called in different stages, first prepparse() for preprocess and then yyparse for the definitive parsing.

Comment: Just compiled, or both linked into the executable?

Comment: gcc -shared -o code/luacall.so code/luacall.c lexyacc/lex.prep.c lexyacc/lex.yy.c lexyacc/y.tab.c code/sqltext.c -fPIC -lssl -lconfig

Comment: I get to run it but when it arrives to the point of calling prepparse I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. I have found I omited one information that has proben important. As I only wanted to alter some tokens and not defining a full language (it is only preparsing) I dind't define a Yacc file, so I was not actually a parser but a Lexer what I had to call. So the command is not preparse but preplex.

I stil don't have it working but I guess it is another different issue.